# why is my CSS table squashed to the side?

Tags: css

I have recently been designing a theme for my forum but my table at the bottom is squashed to one side and no CSS seems to fix it :/

please help me I have spent like 2 hours on this xD

cashcapacity.com

Comment: What css have you tried? can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Add the relevant code in a jsFiddle, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `colspan` attribute. The table actually has 3 - 4 columns.

Try this:

```
<td class="thead" colspan="4">
```

And:

```
<td class="trow" colspan="4">
```

Comment: thanks bro :P I would rep you up if I had the rep xD

Comment: oh sorry didnt see that :P

Comment: oh thanks :P could you answer my other question?